# Magento 1.9 - How to Stop my checkout page from asking for card details?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, credit-card

My website is based on Magento 1.9.3 and Im using the IWD one page checkout extension for a 1 page checkout.

Normal Order Flow:

- Enter customer details
- Select online payment or cash
- If online payment is selected, a line appears below it saying you'll 
  be directed the payment gateway to complete the payment.
- Click place order now button and get directed to gateway, etc.

Error happening now:

- Enter customer details
- If online payment is selected, text fields are appearing below the payment options buttons asking for card details. These are totally useless and any data entered here is lost after clicking place order now.
- After clicking place order, you do get redirected to the payment gateway though.

We havent configured this module and just want the customer to be directed to the payment gateway instead of asking for any card details on the page.

Screenshot below.

Please suggest any good way to get this sorted. Sorry if this is a layman question but Ive googled it and cant find a good solution.

[image]

Comment: You need make custom payment where you can set redirect url in Model class.

Comment: public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
  {
    return Mage::getUrl('custompaymentmethod/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => false));
  }